# Generic class instance with type from PropertyInfo.PropertyType

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, propertyinfo

I have classes like below:

```
public class SampleClassToTest<T>
{
    public static Fake<T> SomeMethod(string parameter)
    {
        // some code
    }

    public static Fake<T> SomeMethod(string parameter, int anotherParameter)
    {
        //some another code
    }
}

public class Fake<T>
{
    // some code
}
```

And I want to use them in this way:

```
SampleClassToTest<MyClass>.SomeMethod("some parameter");
```

The problem which I have is the following: type of "MyClass" I can get only from PropertyInfo instance using Reflection, so I have

```
Type propertyType = propertyInfo.PropertyType;
```

How can I do this? Any ideas?

**UPD.**  I'm trying to pass the Type to generic method. And yes, this is what I want.

Comment: This is unclear, IMO. What are you trying to achieve and what problem is there?

Comment: This is doable with reflection, but once you start using reflection you have no option other than to continue with it *all the way*, which is very slow to run and very tedious to code. Are you sure that's what you want?

Comment: @GrantThomas, I'm trying to pass the Type to generic method. And yes this is what I want.

Comment: @Jon, can you propose a better way for this? I would appreciate!

Comment: There are no generic methods shown in the example... there is a non-generic method on a generic type.

Comment: @user1563880: No, because we have no idea of what you are trying to do in the first place. Obviously any other approach would involve refactoring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to do:

```
typeof(SampleClassToTest<>).MakeGenericType(propertyType)
       .GetMethod("SomeMethod", new Type[] {typeof(string)})
       .Invoke(null, new object[] {"some parameter"});
```

Ugly.

If it can *at all* be helped, I would advise offering a non-generic API that accepts a `Type` instance; the nice thing here is that a generic API can call into a non-generic API trivially by using `typeof(T)`.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want:

```
Type propertyType;
Type classType = typeof(SampleClassToTest<>).MakeGenericType(propertyType);

MethodInfo method = classType.GetMethod("SomeMethod", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public, null, new[] { typeof(string) }, null);
object fake = method.Invoke(null, new object[] { "some parameter" });
```

Comment: both variants are correct, but this http://stackoverflow.com/a/15433260/1563880 is shorter